# angular routes dynamically change route paths

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm having a problem relate to Angular Routing. I have `home.component.ts` file and all the contents are loaded from a module called categories.
Concept is about product and categories. When user clicks on category, it will show products. All of it will be shown in the home page.

home Component html.

```
<app-categories [categories]="categories"></app-categories>
```

I'm parsing a `categories` object to the `categories` module. Afterwards, I used the object the module generate the view in the home page.

categories html

```
  @Input('categories') categories: CategoriesModel;
```

The question is, how can I add routes when i click on a category. Initially it loads

```
localhost:4200/#
```

I need to add routes when I navigate into a category in the home page itself how can I do It.

Comment: This is [basic routing](https://angular.io/guide/router). Consider reading the documentation before asking questions.

Comment: no I don't want to add a separate route for another component. I'm in the home page itself and need  some routes for the home page itself.

Comment: currently, categories is a child to home page, but what about product page. If it replaces categories page, use <router-outlet> instead of <app-categories>, and if product page is a child to categories page, use similar approach as with categories.

Comment: You can either a child component (what you have) or a routed child (what is exaplined in the documentation). You can't have both.

Comment: no thing is category page is a separate component and there can be multiple sub categories inside a category. the issue is after got deep inside a category and finally to the product page  and when I come back it redirect me to the initial home page no the sup category or category. I need to track down where I am.

Comment: Use router-outlet, your project is big enough to need it. You cannot implement with just parent-child relation.